# Cocoa Pod Setup for existing xcode project

Tags: ios

I found these tutorials to create our own cocoapod:

- https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html
- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-your-first-cocoapod--cms-24332

but for me none of them helps, as they create fresh xcode project using pod lib create. I have my own xcode project and I need to setup in that rather than create a fresh one.

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445691/making-a-cocoapod-from-an-existing-xcode-project

Answer (score 0):

1.Delete following files/folder that pod created.
[image]

2.Make sure your Podfile available.
3.Use this command:

```
pod install
```

**Updated**

If you didn't have installed pod in your project. Do like following:
1.Use `pod setup` in your project root folder.
2.Edit Podfile
3.Use this command:

```
pod install
```

Comment: i have only my github repository and i want to create a fresh cocoa pod. How can i do that??

Comment: @AbhishekThapliThapliyal Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this:

1.Run the command on Terminal:- sudo gem install cocoapods

After successfully install CocoaPods

2.Go to that folder where your existing project is saved in your System.

3.After that Run the command for creating Pod file:- Touch podfile

4.After Creating Pod file run the next command:- Open podfile

It will open pod file and here Put the below line and save that file using command+S

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, ‘8.0’

use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0.2’

5.After that run the final command in your Terminal:- pod install

It will take some time to install that file after that once install the all file close the xcode project and again open that project, click on the `.xcworkspace` extension file.

Comment: i compared this project with link i mentioned . These steps unable to create license podspec and readme file

Comment: @AbhishekThapliThapliyal I wrote these steps for existing xcode project and  i did like this pod successfully created.

Comment: Try  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755044/how-to-install-cocoa-pods

Comment: @AbhishekThapliThapliyal I hope now You can do

Comment: Thanks...but that is to install cocoapod in project and use other library like AFNetworking. My question is to create cocoapod of my xcode project..

Comment: @AbhishekThapliThapliyal try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445691/making-a-cocoapod-from-an-existing-xcode-project i hope it would be helpful