# How to develop custom cocoa-pod of your existing Xcode project?

Tags: swift, frameworks, storyboard, cocoapods

If you want to create you own cocoapods with storyboards, XIBs, resources and with other frameworks such as Alamofire, MBProgressHUD etc.

Answer (score 2):

> Easy steps to create Cocoapod from existing xcode project

- Create a repository on your git account (Repo name, check README,
  choose MIT under license).
- Copy the url of your repository.Open terminal and run following command.

  **git clone copied your repository url**
- Now copy your Xcode project inside the cloned repository folder on
  your Mac. Now run following commands

  **git add -u to add all files (if not added use: git add filepath/folder)**

  **git commit -m "your custom message"**

  **git push origin master**
- Create a new release to go to your git repository or run following commands

  **git tag 1.0.0**

  **git push --tags**
- First, we need to make sure that you have CocoaPods installed and
  ready to use in your Terminal. run the following command:

  **sudo gem install cocoapods --pre**

**Creating a Podspec**

- All Pods have a podspec file. A [podspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60054626/cocoapods-issue-with-pod-which-contains-resource-folder-assets-xcassets/60055850#60055850), as its name suggests,
  defines the specifications of the Pod! Now let’s make one, run
  following command on terminal

  **touch PodName.podspec**
- After adding and modifying your .podspec file. Validate your .podspec
  file by hitting following command on terminal

  **pod lib lint**
- Once you validate it successfully without errors run following
  command to register you and build cocoapod respectively

  **pod trunk register**

  **pod trunk push PodName.podspec**

If all goes well, you will get this on terminal

> PodName (1.0.0) successfully published
>
> February 5th, 02:32
>
> https://cocoapods.org/pods/PodName
>
> Tell your friends!

Yeah!!!!! congrats you have got your pod link. Use wherever you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some useful links . You can follow the same.

https://www.appcoda.com/cocoapods-making-guide/

https://www.raywenderlich.com/5823-how-to-create-a-cocoapod-in-swift